# VB Automation with word.document issue

Tags: html, vbscript, ms-office

I have a word document which i open in iframe, using vbscript.
The problem is that it's editable by the user. I don't want to allow the user to change anything in the document. it should be in a read only mode. so i guess i should apply the read only attribute before saving, but i don't know how.
any ideas?

my code looks like this:

```
  Dim oWord
  Dim WordDoc
  Dim rng

  Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set WordDoc = oWord.documents.open("c:\try.doc")
  cnt = WordDoc.Characters.Count
  cnt = cnt - 1
  Set rng = WordDoc.Range(Start:=cnt, End:=cnt)
  rng.Text = vbNewLine & "Added Text!"
  WordDoc.SaveAs "c:\try.doc"
  oWord.Quit
    Set rng = Nothing
  Set oWord = Nothing
  Set WordDoc = Nothing
```

Comment: i didn't think `WordDoc.Range(Start:=cnt, End:=cnt)` would work in VBScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can protect the document before saving it by using this:

WordDoc.Protect Password:="mypassword", NoReset:=False, Type:= wdAllowOnlyReading, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=False

Note that if your application is to make changes to the document later on, you need to turn off the protection before doing changes